# Why is there a tag 'discussion' when every post is part of a discussion?

Tags: discussion, tags

The discussion tag is overused and doesn't help distinguish interesting posts at all, because all posts are discussion anyway.
Maybe tagging parts of the discussion would work better, such as 'claim', 'supporting evidence', 'rebuttal' ?

Comment: I like how you didn't tag this as discussion, because this isn't a feature-request.

Comment: I'll keep to one sentence in future.

Comment: @Servy What, no `meta-tags` tag? ;)

Comment: rebuttal? In a question? Similarly supporting evidence? How can it be supporting evidence when its the opening post

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah, you can't rebut an assertion in an original statement.  Well, that is unless you're attempting to discuss multiple sides of an issue within that post to address the likely concerns of readers in advance.

Comment: @Servy Clearly. That was a joke.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There a 4 major tags on Meta: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and [support](/questions/tagged/support).

They are meant to cover any type of question.

If you simply want to discuss about a certain subject that is related to the site like "your current question" and that it doesn't fit in any of other categories, there you go you have the discussion tab.

The other 1500 + tags are there to be more specific.

Answer (score 15):

Not all Meta posts are discussions.  Some of them are bug reports or support or feature requests.  Everything else is a discussion, like your question.

Comment: Well, to be fair, feature requests are really a subset of discussions.  They're discussing a feature request.  Bugs and support questions aren't discussions at all though.

Comment: Not all feature requests are or need to be discussed, @Servy. Although I agree that that's a technicality. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Not all discussions are or need to be discussed ;)

Comment: @Servy It's not really a requirement, but it is true in practice. We do tend to discuss most feature requests.

Comment: @Servy Amen to that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Tags are there simply to be used as they are intended/required.
A tag being used a great deal doesn't mean it's "overused", as long as it's used correctly, it's just that it's "popular" (there's a distinct difference).

As ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd pointed out, there are 4 "main" tags on MSO and discussion is one of them.

- discussion = 22,154
- feature-request = 15,126
- support = 14,101
- bug = 9,595

Not a lot of difference between them, really.

Ironically, you used *feature-request* tag when you should have used *discussion* tag, as you never actually requested a feature. You just *asked* something, stated a point, and loosely suggested something *might* be better (=discussion).

Though I can see why you wanted to avoid contradiction :P

Comment: Feature request: tagging parts of the discussion would work better, such as 'claim', 'supporting evidence', 'rebuttal' ?

Comment: You missed a valuable word from your quote though, you wrote "*Maybe* tagging parts of the discussion would work better" = discussion. The "*maybe*" indicates you are wanting others to comment on your opinion, it reads more like a question than statement, and certainly isn't "asking for something". Stating "maybe" is not stating explicitly (or even loosely) you would like something done. A feature request would be "please can we have.." "can you implement/change.." "can you do this" etc :)

Comment: The question format tends to be in the form of questions. Suggested improvements suggest a better or other positive state/

Comment: and feature requests are written as a request, asking for something to be implemented or changed explicitly. Loosely stating "something might be better" is not a request.